# Как сравнить float и double?

Tags: c++, float, сравнение, double

Как правильно сравнивать два числа типа `float` и `double`? Следующий способ часто говорит, что одинаковые числа различны:

```
float a = 0.00001001;
double b = 0.00001001;

if (a == b) {
  std::cout << "equal"; // не выводит equal
}
```

Мой вопрос отличается от дубликатов тем, что мне нужно знать, как правильно сравнить 2 числа типа `float` и `double` на C++, а не почему (не только почему) простое сравнение не работает. В привидённых в дубликатах ответах либо ответы для 2 одинаковых типов, либо не сказано как выбирать `epsilon` и т.д..

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86440/discussion-on-question-by-hero---float--double).

Answer (score 7):

```
if (fabs(a - b) <= eps)
```

где `eps` - некая маленькая величина, вообще говоря - зависящая от порядка самих чисел, поэтому более корректно

```
if (fabs(a - b)/ max(fabs(a) + eps, fabs(b) + eps) <= eps)
```

Пример задания `eps`:

```
const
  FuzzFactor = 1000;
  SingleResolutionEps = 1E-7 * FuzzFactor;
  DoubleResolutionEps = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;
```

Откуда это берётся - точность float 23 двоичных разряда или 7-8 десятичных, т.е. число имеет 7 верных десятичных цифр, поэтому меньше `1E-7` eps смысла нет делать.

Почему используется множитель `FuzzFactor = 1000;` - это расширение допуска, чёткого критерия его выбора нет, разработчики этой библиотеки решили так сделать, а вообще множитель можно выбирать в зависимости от желаемой погрешности в младших разрядах.

Для сравнения float и double по правилам сложения погрешностей  следует использовать погрешность для менее точных float, т.е.  порядка `1E-7` даже при приведении float к double, как предложил в комментарии @Grundy -  ведь при этом приведении возникают дополнительные ничем не обеспеченные разряды с погрешностью в пределах всё тех же `1E-7`.

Труды по точности float-арифметики: [1](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)  [2](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) [Goldberg](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

Comment: Уточните, *как* вычислить правильный `eps`? ;-)

Comment: .. .и как же установить значение для `eps`?

Comment: А что за `FuzzFactor`?

Comment: Похоже, вы жертва того же заблуждения, что эпсилон это константа. Сравните, пожалуйста, float 0,000000000567 и float 0,000000000568 с использованием 1E-7 ;-)

Comment: Если  точность результата нужна до 1e-7, то для нас не имеет значения, что творится "на хвосте" и такие значения для нас равны

Comment: @Kromster Кто жертва? Что не так с этим сравнением? По приведенной формуле `1E-12/5E-10 = 0.002 > 1e-7`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вы ввели новую сущность - точность результата, к которой видимо предъявили требования быть 1е-7 - т.е. вы жестко задали Эпсилон для некоторой задачи. Заметьте, что в вопросе этого нет. Вопрос спрашивает, как сравнить.

Comment: Потом был вопрос, а как выбирать Эпсилон и мы все вместе дали ответ. Зачетку давать, или на пересдачу прийти?

Comment: @MBo похоже вы правы, извиняюсь. Уточните плиз, что такое FuzzFactor.

Comment: @Hero, Например: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon

Comment: @Grundy там в примере не такое сравнение, как в ответе. Почему? Для какого типа брать `std::numberic_limits`: `float` или `double`?

Comment: @FuzzFactor совокупность всех ошибок, кроме ошибки округления. тут взята с потолка.

К примеру если вы умножаете 2 флоата, то ошибка уже E-6 и так далее

Comment: @Hero, обрати внимание, что по ссылке сравниваются параметры с одинаковым типом. Если типы разные, очевидно, нужно привести к какому-либо одному.

Comment: я бы добавил что правильный эпсилон можно посчитать по вузовским методичкам в разделе "ПОГРЕШНОСТИ  КОСВЕННЫХ  ИЗМЕРЕНИЙ"

Answer (score 2):

Машинный эпсилон это одно,а точность входных данных в задаче это совсем другое.
Редко бывает, чтобы точность входных данных в задаче была равна машинному эпсилону.
Обычно точность входных данных в задаче гораздо меньше, чем машинный эпсилон.
Есть целая наука об правилах округления и отбрасывания незначащих цифр.
Исходя из этой науки и выбирается в каждом конкретном случае эпсилон для каждой конкретной задачи.

А машинный эпсилон это характеристика данной вычислительной системы.