# Неправильный подсчет long double

Tags: c

Имеется вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
long double s21_atofLong(const char *str) {
  long int length = strlen(str);
  long double returnValue = 0;
  int counterE = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    int i = 0;
                if ((str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'I')
         && (str[i + 1] == 'n' || str[i + 1] == 'N')
         && (str[i + 2] == 'f' || str[i + 2] == 'F')) {
          returnValue = INFINITY;
         }
                if ((str[i] == 'N' || str[i] == 'n')
         && (str[i + 1] == 'a' || str[i + 1] == 'A')
         && (str[i + 2] == 'N' || str[i + 2] == 'n')) {
          returnValue = NAN;
         }

    if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-') {
      if (str[i] == '-') {
        sign = -1;
      }
      i++;
    }
    while(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
      returnValue = returnValue * 10 + (str[i] - 48);
      i++;
    }
    if (str[i] == '.') {
      i++;
    }
    int pow1 = 1;
    while(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
      returnValue = returnValue + (str[i] - 48.0) / (10 * pow1);
      i++;
      pow1 = pow1 * 10;
    }
    if (str[i] == 'e') {
      i++;
    }
    int signE = 1;
    if (str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-') {
      if (str[i] == '-') {
        signE = -1;
      }
      i++;
    }
    while(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
      counterE = counterE * 10 + (str[i] - 48);
      i++;
    }
    returnValue = returnValue * pow(10, signE * counterE);
  return sign * returnValue;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    long double a1 = 1, a2 = 1;

    const char str[] = "53.123";
    const char fstr[] = "%Lf";

    a1 = s21_atofLong(str);
    sscanf(str, fstr, &a2);

printf("%.25Lf %.25Lf", a1, a2);


  return 0;
}
```

Почему из `sscanf` я получаю немного другое значение, а не как в своей функции?

```
53.1230000000000000051625371
53.1230000000000000016930901
```

Ну и получается что при сравнении значений с максимальной точностью получаю, что они не равны. Как правильно будет посчитать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913542/

Comment: 10-чное : `53.123` ; 2-ичное : `110101.000(1111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011000000100000110001001001101110100101111000110101001)` - бесконечная периодическая и в 64 бита не влазит....

Comment: `scanf` решает задачу максимум - отыскать вещественное число наиболее близкое к заданной десятичной дроби. Обратите внимание что сама десятичная дробь может не иметь точного представления. То есть, вам надо подыскать вещественное значение близкое ... к чему? К чему-то что вы даже выразить средствами вещественных чисел не можете. Надеюсь, я объяснил почему `scanf` устроен внутри сложно. Ваш метод использует неточные вычисления (из которых `pow` - худшее), по этому вы получаете другой результат. Если вы намерены решить задачу примерно, используйте примерное равенство. Иначе - сложно и интересно.

Answer (score 5):

Дробное число невозможно задать точно потому что размер переменной не бесконечен. На каждом шаге оно будет округляться до ближайшего двоичнозадаваемого числа. Разное количество операций приводит к разному округлению.

Сравнивать числа с фиксированной и с плавающей точкой можно только через выражения **вроде** `abs(a-b) < 0.0000000001`. Значение подбирается исходя из оценки максимальной погрешности и требованиям к точности.

Обычно это значение зависит от погрешности вводимых данных. Минимальное значение должно быть в 2 раза больше максимальной [погрешности косвенных измерений](http://library.mephi.ru/pdftunnel.php?Z21FAMILY=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&Z21ID=49730&PATH=book-mephi%2FUIL%2FAksenova_Metody_ocenki_pogreshnostej_rezultatov_pryamyh_i_kosvennyh_izmerenij_v_laboratoriyah_fizicheskogo_praktikuma_2009.pdf).

Comment: Стоит только добавить, что правильно использовать не `0.0000000001`, а Epsilon зависящий от масштаба сравниваемых значений.

Comment: @Kromster По-нормальному вообще надо смотреть на предметную область и исходя из неё выбирать эпсилон )  Какая точность требуется там.

Comment: потому там и стоит слово "вроде" =)

Comment: Эпсилон не часть предметной области, а часть данных. Каждому вещественному числу должен быть придан свой эпсилон. Иногда, определённой группе чисел, может быть придан один и тот же эпсилон, но это не делает его частью предметной области.

Comment: Конкретно эта задача формулируется без эпсилон: построить вещественное число наиболее близкое к заданной десятичной дроби. Мы говорим в вводе значении вообще, никаких эпсилонов, только наиболее точный возможный результат.